# Send parameters to strapi custom api

Tags: json, database, api, parameters, strapi

I need to send parameters to a custom api made in strapi.

The controller `category.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  async findCustom(ctx) {
    console.log(ctx.params);
    const { userId, categoryId } = ctx.params;
    var res = await strapi.connections.default.raw(
      `SELECT
      user_id,
      category
  FROM
      categories
  WHERE
      user_id = ${userId} AND category = ${categoryId}`
    );

    return res;
  },
};
```

The `routes.json`:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/categories/custom",
  "handler": "category.findCustom",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```

How do I get it to take the parameters sent from:

```
http://localhost:1337/categories/custom?userId=2&categoryId=1
```

Comment: warning - your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Hello @DanielA.White I know, anyway I need to know how can I get the parameters from the url so that I can return the query based on those parameters. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strapi uses koa - [check this out](https://devdocs.io/koa/api/request.md#requestquery).

You can get them inside your handler like this:

```
async findCustom(ctx) {
  const queryObj = ctx.request.query
  //rest of method
}
```

For your request the object will contain:

```
{
  userId: '2',
  categoryId: '1'
}
```

-----------------------*Adding warnings to the answer*----------------------
Expanding on  @Daniel A. White's cooment -
You are really exposing yourself by allowing parts of an SQL query to be injected directly into a soon-to-be ran query. Just be careful if moving to production/public - **understanding SQL injection is a must here**.
Also adding suggested reads for dangers of **Information exposure**:
[Should sensitive data ever be passed in the query string?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string)
[Information exposure through query strings in url](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url)